# Can't connect to local MySQL server using Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

Please help me to solve this problem:

I am using docker to create a mysql container and initialize a database in it automatically based on mysql:8.0.19. But when I get into the container and enter the pass word after 'mysql -u root -p', it is said that:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

There are four files: Dockerfile, schema.sql, privileges.sql, setup.sh

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql:8.0.19

# allow no password
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD yes

# copy file into container
COPY setup.sh /mysql/setup.sh
COPY schema.sql /mysql/schema.sql
COPY privileges.sql /mysql/privileges.sql

# exec these command when container start up
CMD ["sh", "/mysql/setup.sh"]
```

**setup.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'checking mysql status.'
service mysql status

echo '1.start mysql....'
service mysql start
sleep 3
service mysql status

echo '2.start importing data....'
mysql < /mysql/schema.sql
echo '3.end importing data....'

sleep 3
service mysql status

echo '4.start changing password....'
mysql < /mysql/privileges.sql
echo '5.end changing password....'

sleep 3
service mysql status
echo 'mysql is ready'

tail -f /dev/null
```

**privileges.sql:**

```
use mysql;
select host, user, plugin from user;

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**schema.sql:**

```
create database `collector`;
use collector;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `EVENT`;
CREATE TABLE `EVENT` (
 `ID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `EventType`VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EventID` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EpcID` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TimeStamp` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `EVENT` (`ID`, `EventType`, `EventID`, `EpcID`, `TimeStamp`)
VALUES('0','0','0','0',0.0);
```

I think privileges.sql might be the one that causing the problem, but i have no idea how to solve it.

By the way I use:

```
docker build . -t mysql_service:1.0
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_service -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql_service:1.0
```

to build and run.

Answer (score 0):

To set a root password use `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456`.

`MYSQL_DATABASE=collector` is also available to create the database and use it as the default.

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aren't needed for `ALTER USER`.

The docker container doesn't have a init so `service ...` commands won't work. Also the `mysqld` isn't running in the build stage.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ under `Initializing a fresh instance` you can put SQL files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` to initialize the database.

Comment: Thank you very much! I deleted privileges.sql and setup.sh then used ADD to just move schema.sql into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d,and it worked!